# Android JAVA 8 MinSDK

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-min-sdk

Let's say I'm not using any JAVA 8 specific features, but in Project Structure I have Source & Target Compatibility set to 1.8 - will this alone cause any problems on lower API targets (lower then API level 24) ?

Was trying to find an answer at the following link but it only seems to reference JAVA 8 specific features:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: no it will not cause problems

Comment: It will not create any problem. Lint will throw warnings if any Java 8 specific features won't run below API 24. For example, Collections streams if used and min SDK is set to 19, then it will warnings.